# How to initialize List<double[][]>?

Tags: c#, list, matrix

I tried to do so:

```
rotation[0] = new double[3][];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    rotation[0][i] = new double[3];
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: May be you should use double[,]?

Comment: Where are you using List in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `rotation` is your `List<double[][]>`, you can do it like this:

```
var tmp = new double[3][];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    tmp[i] = new double[3];
}
rotation.Add(tmp);
```

You can also do it using LINQ:

```
rotation.Add(Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => new double[3]).ToArray());
```

Both fragments above add a single 3x3 array of `double`s to a `List<double[][]>`.

If you need a list of three items, you can do it like this:

```
List<double[][]> rotation = new List<double[][]>();
for (int r = 0 ; r != 3 ; r++) {
    var tmp = new double[3][];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        tmp[i] = new double[3];
    }
    rotation.Add(tmp);
}
```

or

```
List<double[][]> rotation = new List<double[][]>();
for (int r = 0 ; r != 3 ; r++) {
    rotation.Add(Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => new double[3]).ToArray());
}
```

or even

```
var rotation = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 3)
    .Select(r => Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => new double[3]).ToArray());
```

Comment: I try to do clock, List<double[][]> rotation = new List<double[][]>(3) make 3 matrix for rotation second, minute and hour arrows.

Comment: @user1924922 Then you need to repeat this three times in a loop.

Comment: Can you write me an example? :)

Comment: And one more question: How to contact with some matrix? (Example for 
double[][] rotation; is "Matrix.Make2DRotation(angle, rotation);")

Comment: In general how to contact with elements of matrixes in List?

Comment: @user1924922 use the `[]` operator: for example, `rotation[0]`, `rotation[1]`, or `rotation[2]`.

Comment: But it doesn't work, it call ArgumentOutOfRange exception. Make2DRotation assign values to matrix rotation[0]. It has the title: public static void Make2DRotation(double angle, double[][] ret)

Comment: I forgot to delete List<double[][]> from constructor of class. Thanks for your help. You helped me very much! :)